# The projects on Android studio stuck

Tags: xml, android-studio

Although I created various projects ,however my apps stop at this point
And I am receiving that error

C:\Users\Pulp Fiction.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\4ebac0cfc4914a1ef32352d70fea221e\jetified-incdeclibrary-0.0.5\res\values\values.xml:8:5-429: AAPT: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/textSize' with config ''.

I tried these methods

Clean project
Invalid caches and restart
Rename textSize for textSizeR

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share \res\values\values.xml file!!!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like mixing several support-lib versions in one project. Please share a demo in eg. github.com and we can help you